# Is the version of the linux kernel listed in the source some where?

Tags: linux, documentation, version, source-code

If I'm looking at a version of the linux kernel source code, can I tell which version of the kernel it is?

This is code that's currently not running on any platform (so I can't execute commands), but is there any source file that lists the kernel version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `/usr/src/linux/.config` , header files in `/usr/src/linux/include/generated` , `/usr/src/linux/include/config/kernel.release`

If you have a vmlinux file, try 
        `strings vmlinux | grep version`

Comment: Or `strings vmlinux | grep "Linux Version"`

Answer (score 5):

In 4.0, you can run:

```
make kernelversion
```

Sample output:

```
4.0.0
```

Possible same question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151694/how-to-find-the-version-of-a-linux-kernel-source-tree

Comment: Alternatively ```head Makefile``` from top level of kernel source